# JavaScript RegExp: Retrieve part of a String using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String with the value of something like so: `"H798asdhka80:124htg"`

I want to retrieve from this string (and similarly structured strings) every character before the colon ":" so my new string would look like this: `H798asdhka80`

What would the code to do this look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `substr`:

```
var str = "H798asdhka80:124htg",
    strpart = str.substr(0,str.indexOf(':'));
```

or `slice`

```
var str = "H798asdhka80:124htg",
    strpart = str.slice(0,str.indexOf(':'));
```

or `split`

```
var strpart = "H798asdhka80:124htg".split(/:/)[0];
```

or `match`

```
var str = "H798asdhka80:124htg".match(/(^.+)?:/)[1];
```

or `replace`

```
var str = "H798asdhka80:124htg".replace(/:.+$/,'');
```

or create a more generic `String.prototype` extension

```
String.prototype.sliceUntil = function(str){
  var pos = this.indexOf(str);
  return this.slice(0, (pos>-1 ? pos : this.length));
}
var str = "H798asdhka80:124htg".sliceUntil(':124');
```

Answer (score 6):

use

```
var str="H798asdhka80:124htg".split(':')[0]
```

Using `split(':')` you get the array `["H798asdhka80","124htg"]`. And then use only the first element of that array.

Comment: Where is the reg exp like the poster asked? :)

Comment: @epascarello There's no need to use reg exp, I think it's better and simpler this way

Answer (score 3):

A reg exp answer, match anything from the start of the string to the colon.

```
var str = "H798asdhka80:124htg";
var txt = str.match(/^[^:]+/);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"H798asdhka80:124htg".split(':')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a RegExp for this. This should work for you:

```
str.split(':')[0];
```

Anyway, the other way would be to `replace` the unneeded part of the string with a regular expression, like this:

```
str.replace(/:.+$/, '');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/p3nxg/)